# How to add server-side processed data from code-behind to javascript in .aspx page in asp.net using c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I am making a web-application in asp.net. I need a page turning effect, so i used turn.js (ref: http://www.turnjs.com/). Now i need to process some data on server side i.e code-behind and send it to client side. I downloaded the project from above web-site (from: https://github.com/blasten/turn.js). But the problem is that I can't figure out how to send the data from the code-behind to the JavaScript in the .aspx page which is actually loading dynamic pages.

```
function addPage(page, book) {
        //  First check if the page is already in the book
        if (!book.turn('hasPage', page)) {
            // Create an element for this page
            var element = $('<div />', {'class': 'page '+((page%2==0) ? 'odd' : 'even'), 'id': 'page-'+page}).html('<i class="loader"></i>');
            // If not then add the page
            book.turn('addPage', element, page);
            // Let's assum that the data is comming from the server and the request takes 1s.
            setTimeout(function(){
                    element.html('<div class="data">Data for page '+page+'</div>');
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

This is the JavaScript function which adds the dynamic pages. How to add the content of the page in the line `element.html('<div class="data">Data for page '+page+'</div>');`.

Answer (score 0):

in your aspx page
    element.html('<%=pageData%>')

in your code behind create a public string called pageData  and then in your code (parhaps page Load event) put the string of data that you want into pageData

Or you can create a web service or just a simple ashx file, to respond with the required data and use ajax to get the next page data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you ask.

1. Add an asp:Literal control into your javascript function. Set its content in the code behind.

   ```
       setTimeout(function(){
               element.html('<div class="data">Data for page '+<asp:Literal runat="server" Id="litPageData"></asp:Literal>+'</div>');
       }, 1000);
   ```
2. Add a hidden field, set it in the code behind, and access the value in your Javascript.

   ```
   <asp:Hidden runat="server" id="hidPageData"></asp:Hidden>
   ```

   (I might be a little off on the syntax for this one)

   ```
       setTimeout(function(){
               element.html('<div class="data">Data for page '+$('#<%= hidPageData.ClientId%>').val() +'</div>');
       }, 1000);
   ```
3. Symeon's solution, already posted.

Answer (score 0):

In your codebehind for instance code.cs declare a variable:

```
String strDummyValues = "Dummy value";
```

in your ASPX page:

Use `<%=strDummyValues%>` means

```
element.html('<div class="data">Data for page '+<%=strDummyValues%>+'</div>');
```